# Selecting Columns as rows Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I have table (Medical Invoice) joined with 5 foreign keys
every row has one value of these FKs like this :

```
    ID   PDL_ID   LTT_ID   MSF_ID   RIY_ID   ORN_ID   AMOUNT
    1    null     1        null     null     null     20.00
    2    null     null     1        null     null     15.00
    3    1        null     null     null     null     10.00
    4    null     null     3        null     null     18.00
```

and i want the result be like this

```
    col1(IDs)  col2(values)   col3(Amount)   
    PDL_ID      1             10
    LTT_ID      1             20
    MSF_ID      1             15
    MSF_ID      3             18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to use `union all`:

```
select t.*
from ((select 'POL_ID' as col1, POL_ID as col2, Amount from invoices
      ) union all
      (select 'LTT_ID' as col1, LTT_ID as col2, Amount from invoices
      ) union all
      (select 'MSF_ID' as col1, MSF_ID as col2, Amount from invoices
      )
     ) t
where col2 is not null;
```

If you have lots and lots of data, there are other approaches that do not require reading the table for each column.

Comment: thanks,i want to join every ID (PDL_ID,LTT_ID,..) with its look up what is the best and fast way to retrieve the date ?

Comment: @Sawalhah . . . I believe this answers the question that you asked.  If you have another question, the appropriate way to ask is as a question, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 11g and higher you can use operator `unpivot`:

```
select col1, col2, amount from invoice
  unpivot (col2 for col1 in ("PDL_ID", "LTT_ID", "MSF_ID", "RIY_ID", "ORN_ID"))
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6bf1a/1)</sup>

Comment: thanks,I'm using Oracle 12c and i tried the unpivot
but, what if i want to join on of these IDs (LTT_ID) with another lookup table like lab_test_details  ?

Comment: Simple join like here: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/163659/1) works. If you have more complicated situation - please edit your question.

Comment: every row shows one single value of join table 
e.g: row 1 has ltt_id = 1, in the join table (lab_test_details) it represent the "description 1" of lab_test_details
row 2 has msf_id = 1,in the join table (medical_service) it represent the "description 1" medical_service and so ..
-what are the changes should i do on the question -

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to join five different TABLES to unpivoted result and use corresponding ID's from them. So construct join and displayed information like [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/80298/1).
I'm partially guessing your data structure and requirements, you should clearly explain them in your original question, this way you have better chance for correct answer.